# Getting only one value that matches my search in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

So I want to go over a dictionary searching for the value `True`. If it finds it, I'd like to return the Key that matched with the value.

I tried using `d.get(True)` but that returns all of the keys. I only need the first one it could find.

Any ideas how to do so?

Thanks

Comment: post your input dict

Comment: If you need to search a key in a dict by its value then you are doing *something* wrong. It beats the entire purpose of using a dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop over the dictionary with `for`

```py
d = {...}

for i in d:
    if d[i]:
        return i
```

That, or the dictionary should be "backwards" to what you are using. That would be the correct way of using a dictionary.

```
d = {True: [...], False: [...]}
```

Comment: Don't rush posting an answer until you're positive that it's **complete** and correct. Hint: `return i` :)

Comment: I hadn't thought of DeepSpace's clever remark yet

Comment: `if d[i]:` is true for any truthy value that `d[i]` holds.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a reverse lookup dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dct = {a: bool(a & 1) for a in range(7)}
# {0: False, 1: True, 2: False, 3: True, 4: False, 5: True, 6: False}

rev = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in dct.items():
    rev[value].append(key)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {False: [0, 2, 4, 6], True: [1, 3, 5]})
```

now `rev[True]` would return all the previous keys that had `True` as value.